# How to reduce fixed-wing FPV wobble?

Tags: first-person-view, fixed-wing

I've been flying fixed wing and quadcopter FPV for a while, and one problem all the planes have is they wobble or get bumped around by turbulence, even on relatively calm days.

Are there types of plane where this is less of a problem?

Or anything else I can do to get smooth video?

I started with an EasyStar, and thought the dihedral and general stability was over-reacting to turbulence. Then I tried a wing, which wobbles in yaw, presumably because it doesn't have much fin area. I've also tried a couple of twin-boom pushers, which seem just as bad.